# loading external pages within website

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a table in database which stores links submitted by users, I want my users to use those links whenever they want but the problem i am facing is 
I can retrive and display the links with this code

```
<td width="560"><font color="#999">
<a href="'.$row['link'].'?action=tagtoload"  class="tagToload">'.$row['link'].'</a>
</font>
</td>
```

but it generates link like this

`http://XYZ.com/www.pxleyes.com/blog/2011/12/these-50-photos-will-blow-you-away/?action=tagtoload`
so when the users click on this links it says page not found.

I want to open the links within my page so i have added ?action=tagtoload
which will load pages within my page with ajax call but the things are not working.

yes `XYZ.com` is my domain and for not generated links `xyz.com/abc?action=tagtoload` is working fine. its coming just below top header i want all external links to be below my header. can you please tell how i can open these links under my header. I want to display these links as anchored link so that user can see what these items are and when users clicks on these links it should open in iframe or whatever but under my header –

Answer (score 2):

Guessing that XYZ.com stands for your domain:

[add http:// for external links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204736/a-href-only-will-send-me-to-subdirecteries-and-not-anywhere-else/9204748#9204748)

Concerning the ajax-Problem:
Is it working with fixed, not generated links? Please post also the output of the php file and your ajax-code.

Please also define 'in you page': In an iframe? div? replacing your window?

**EDIT:**

To 'fix' you 'php-code':

```
<td width="560">
 <font color="#999">
<a href="<?php print $row['link'] ?>?action=tagtoload"  class="tagToload">
  <?php print $row['link'] ?></a>
</font>
</td>
```

1. Please get familiar with html and php first.
2. do NOT use `<font>`, use css instead
3. use css instead of putting the width in the td as an attribute
4. read http://php.net/

Comment: yes XYZ.com is my domain and for not generated links xyz.com/abc?action=tagtoload  is working fine .its coming just below top header i want all external links to be below my header.can you please tell how i can open these links under  my header.i want to display these links as anchored link so that user can see what these items are and when users clicks on these links it should open in iframe or whatever but under my header

Comment: "Please post the the output of the php file and your ajax-code."